# Error Using tapply() to add column to data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to add the results (initially from tapply) back to the data frame. I am trying to sum the values in df$new by df$PropertyID and return them in a new column in the same data frame. I am able to use tapply to pull the values out, but I am having difficulty getting adding them back to the data frame. Below is a sample of my data frame.

| PropertyID | NumUnits | AvgAskingRentPerUnit | new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | NA | NA | NA |
| 58 | 38 | NA | NA |
| 95 | NA | NA | NA |
| 169 | NA | NA | NA |
| 657 | NA | NA | NA |
| 709 | 1 | NA | NA |
| 709 | 14 | 2507 | 35098 |
| 709 | 20 | 1753 | 35060 |
| 709 | 40 | 1731 | 69240 |
| 709 | 17 | 2207 | 37519 |

I tried using the below codes

1. `tapply(new, PropertyID, sum)` ...also
2. `new2 <- with(df, tapply(new, PropertyID, sum))` ...
3. also

   ```r
   new2 <- with(df, tapply(new, PropertyID, sum))
   df$new2 <- new2[match(df$PropertyID,names(new2))]
   ```

However, the results do not align with the correct PropertyID. For example, below is the sorted output from running code 3)

| PropertyID | NumUnits | AvgAskingRentPerUnit | new | new2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 58 | 38 | NA | NA | NA |
| 95 | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 169 | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 657 | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 709 | 1 | NA | NA | NA |
| 709 | 14 | 2507 | 35098 | NA |
| 709 | 20 | 1753 | 35060 | NA |
| 709 | 40 | 1731 | 69240 | NA |
| 709 | 17 | 2207 | 37519 | NA |

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `tapply` summarizes the data by group, it would be easier to use `ave` which returns a vector the same length as the input: `with(df, ave(new, PropertyID, FUN = function(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)))` or similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### base R

Perhaps you should be using `ave`?

```r
with(dat, ave(new, PropertyID, FUN = function(z) sum(z, na.rm = TRUE)))
#  [1]      0      0      0      0      0 176917 176917 176917 176917 176917
```

### tidyverse

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(PropertyID) %>%
  mutate(new2 = sum(new, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 10 x 5
#    PropertyID NumUnits AvgAskingRentPerUnit   new   new2
#         <int>    <int>                <int> <int>  <int>
#  1          3       NA                   NA    NA      0
#  2         58       38                   NA    NA      0
#  3         95       NA                   NA    NA      0
#  4        169       NA                   NA    NA      0
#  5        657       NA                   NA    NA      0
#  6        709        1                   NA    NA 176917
#  7        709       14                 2507 35098 176917
#  8        709       20                 1753 35060 176917
#  9        709       40                 1731 69240 176917
# 10        709       17                 2207 37519 176917
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dat[, new2 := sum(new, na.rm = TRUE), by = .(PropertyID)]
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(PropertyID = c(3L, 58L, 95L, 169L, 657L, 709L, 709L, 709L, 709L, 709L), NumUnits = c(NA, 38L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 14L, 20L, 40L, 17L), AvgAskingRentPerUnit = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2507L, 1753L, 1731L, 2207L), new = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 35098L, 35060L, 69240L, 37519L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```